# JavaScript library for switching screens

Tags: javascript

I am looking for JavaScript library which allows to switch screens like it's done in iOS.
It's ok if it will be with buttons (not touch). The main thing is smooth switching screens.
Thanks.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/ ... you really should accept some answers.

Comment: Please define what a "screen" is. Is it a web page? Part of a web page? A browser window? A pop-up window?

Comment: @Diodeus it's just a div

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)

Comment: I'm using Sencha Touch 2 Beta and it's awesome. Highly recommended.